# Flutter :Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher'

Tags: android, flutter

Image of my drwables folder

[image]

I have following errors in my manifeast.xml file. I not able to get notification due notification icon error. Following are my error listed.

1. URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)
2. URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)
3. Unresolved class '{applicationName}'
4. Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher'
5. `MainActivity` must extend android.app.Activity
6. Cannot resolve symbol '@style/LaunchTheme'
7. Cannot resolve symbol '@style/NormalTheme'
   this all showing in red colour.

If any one can solve this its really appreciate.

**Following are my manifest file code:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.aleyia_azadari_schedule"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android ">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"
        tools:node="remove" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:label="Azadari Schedule"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```